# Glassfish Https on Servlet without server delivering public keys?

Tags: java, ssl, servlets, glassfish, keytool

Is it possible to create a HTTPS connection to a java-servlet with a static name (like https://.../logonServlet) so that only clients who already own the public key/certificate can access the servlet? I would like to prevent the server from delivering public certificates and refusing all other clients?

To my knowledge:
I read about the java keytool and the different stores (keystore (certs and private keys) and truststore (client side, public keys)). I am currently reading the book "Glassfish Security" by Masoud Kalali to learn about user groups and different security realms and stuff like different xml options for server configuration but I feel like I start mixing everything in my head so I would like to ask if you could help me with my desire from above.
A big question that is still open to me is "Why do we need certificates?". Shouldn't be a private key which will be kept secret enough and a public key for the clients?

@Edit

> What you may want to check is SSL/TLS with client authentication. In this setup, the clients need a certificate and a private key as well. The server will refuse connections if they are not from a client with a trusted certificate. This means that server and client need both a keystore and a truststore.

Seems like you are correct, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymetric cryptography works with two elements by design:

- Public key: Shared with everybody, so they can know it's you who send the messages. Also to cipher messages that only can be read with the private key.
- Private key: Only known to you, so you can guarantee that you are who send the messages. Also to read messages sent to you ciphered using your public key.

In a typical HTTPS setup, the server has the certificate (with a public key) and the private key, but the public part is shared with anyone who connects (you can see the certificate of any HTTPS site in the browser).
This is because usually, the client needs to know who the server is, but the server doesn't need to know who the user is (and if it does, other ways like passwords are cheaper and more convenient for the average user).
Sharing the server's public certificate is necessary for SSL/TLS to work, so there is no way to hide those keys and completing the handshake at the same time.

So no, **the server's public key cannot be used to authenticate the clients**, as it is assumed by design that everybody can get it.

What you may want to check is SSL/TLS with client authentication. In this setup, the clients need a certificate and a private key as well. The server will refuse connections if they are not from a client with a trusted certificate. This means that server and client need both a keystore and a truststore.

Note that keystore and truststore are conceptual terms. A single file (.jks, for example) can act as both, as it can contain private keys and public certificates at the same time. That said, they tend to be in different files.

Comment: I am in well knowledge about the mathematical side of asymmetric key cryptography. I know what a public and private key is and I also know that they can be used to sign documents to verify their validity. The second part of my question was more about "Why the certificate and that is something that does not get clearer for me reading your answer. The last part of your answer is interessting will add an edit to my question to probably receive a way to realize it with glassfish and a java client.

Comment: Apart from the cryptography, another part of this design is trust, and it is what provides the value to this authentication method. In order to trust a certificate you must trust the issuer (that's what the truststores are for). The issuer signs the entity certificate and this means that one can verify that the credentials are from a trusted source and not self made. Don't know if this answers your question about "why" or not, let me know and I will try to be more specific.